# How to refresh file list in Android SAF

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

SAF does not appear to refresh the list of files. I've tested this on a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android KitKat.

When I use an application that accesses the the default `Downloads` provider in SAF, I'm seeing files that have already been deleted. Right now I have two files, I confirmed this by checking `/sdcard/Download/` with adb and by used the phone's `My Files` app, yet SAF displays a list of well over one hundred files. The result is that when I select one of those already deleted files, the app tells me the file does not exist (which is of course correct).

Is anyone else facing this issue? Any solutions to refresh the list displayed by SAF?

---

Update: tried it with a Nexus 5 and Android 5.1 and the same thing happens. I believe I misinterpreted the objective of the `Downloads` provider.

The `Downloads` provider, available through SAF, shows a history of downloaded files (which usually end up in the download folder). If we go to the download directory and delete files, these files will not be deleted from the `Downloads` provider because it is showing the **history** of downloaded files and not a list of actual files present in the directory.

When adding a file through copy/paste in nautilus, after mounting the phone in ubuntu, this file does not show in the `Downloads` provider.

So how do we get rid of this history? There is an application called, wait for it, Downloads. Open the application and delete files there or clear all of them like I did and the files go away.

(Google drive SAF provider correctly mirrors what you do outside of it so using that for testing.)

Comment: "I'm seeing files that have already been deleted" -- how did you delete them? It is the responsibility of the provider to use `notifyChange()` to indicate a change in the availability of files. The Downloads provider should either be using a `FileObserver` or a `ContentObserver` on `MediaStore` to detect when files it manages are deleted. If it is not doing that, or not calling `notifyChange()` when it happens, I doubt that there is much we can do about it.

Comment: Some files were deleted through the default file explorer of the smartphone, `My Files`, others through nautilus after mounting the phone in ubuntu.

Comment: @Daniel, did you find the answer to your question?

Comment: "did you find the answer to your question?" --- The `Downloads` provider appears to be showing the history of downloaded files and not a list of actual files present in the directory (unless they wanted it to show the list of actual files and implemented it wrong). That is why it is not refreshed when I delete a file. If using a different provider the files are refreshed just fine. Also, see the comment of CommonsWare above about signaling a change in the list of available files.

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe 4 years later and this is still an issue.  Especially with scoped storage being mandatory starting next year with Android 11.  I have posted a bug issue with Google today but I'm sure they must have been contacted by many other developers.  Any solutions found yet?